# Need help in declaring "forward declarations" in c++

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, ros

I have the forward declaration as follows:

```
class message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image>;
class message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::Image,sensor_msgs::Image>;
```

I am using the above instead of declaring the same in header because I am using the Qt4 to construct a GUI
and also  use  **Boost** libraries in which some of the **signals** and **slots** are used which come in conflict with the **Boost** libraries (as they also contain **signals** and **slots**).

Right now i get the following error message

> error: ‘message_filters’ has not been declared

I do not understand what the problem is. Kindly, help me out with this.

Answer (score 2):

If message_filters is a namespace, you have to forward declare Subscriber like that:

```
namespace message_filters {
    class Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image>;
    class TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::Image,sensor_msgs::Image>;
}
```

Comment: Yes message_filters is a name space. I followed your suggestion and now  get :  `error: ‘Subscriber’ is not a template` and `‘TimeSynchronizer’ is not a template`